# html RegEx: Matching a number followed by a space within a link

Tags: html, regex, web-scraping, httprequest

I want to match this link with a regex to scrape the value (e.g. 8.026,00)  from a website. Since the link is unique, I take it as the identifier for the value (which changes frequently).

```
<a href="randomlink">8.026,00 </a>
```

**When hardcoding the value it matches:**

```
(<a href="randomlink">)(8.026,00 )(<\/a>)
```

**When trying to make it variable it fails:**

```
(<a href="randomlink">)(^[+-]?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:.\d{3})*)(?:\,\d*)?$ )(<\/a>)
```

The variable part does work on the number alone. However, it also fails when having a space behind the number alone. Inserting afterwards \s* does not work. As it does not work within the whole expression.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance. As you might guess, I am fairly new to regex...

Comment: You still have the `^` *start* and `$` *end* [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) inside your full pattern. This fails of course, remove them.

Comment: Just confirm one thing please: are you trying to parse the actual HTML with regex?

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine. I forgot about the anchors.